# Can't identify this LEGO set with large angled brown plates

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Can any one help identify this LEGO set?

Because I can't find instructions to build it!

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have some of the parts for [Jabba's Sail Barge](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75020-1#T=P) #75020

[image]

It is one of the few sets to have so many of the Hinge Plate 2 x 4 with Pin Hole and 3 Holes in light bluish gray, you show 7.  It also has the  12 x 3 Wedge Plates in reddish brown, as well as the reddish brown 2 x 3 Tile with 2 Clips, and reddish brown 2 x 14 plates.